# How to Handle PartialView form submit action in Bootstrap tab panel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I have bootstrap tabs with 5 tabs. each tabs contains Partial View. when I post the form in Partial View from any tab then I want to stay on same tab after form submit successfully or if model validation fires. Currently, if I post form in Partial view then it loads full view and display first tab partial view

```html
Tabpenl.cshtml

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xl-12">
           <h3> 
           First tab
           </h3>
         <section>
            @Html.Partial("_Example1")
         </section>
         
          <h3> 
           Second tab
           </h3>
         <section>
            @Html.Partial("_Example2")
         </section>
         
          <h3> 
           Third tab
           </h3>
         <section>
            @Html.Partial("_Example3")
         </section>
         
          <h3> 
           Fourth tab
           </h3>
         <section>
            @Html.Partial("_Example4")
         </section>
         
          <h3> 
           Firth tab
           </h3>
         <section>
            @Html.Partial("_Example5")
         </section>
         
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

_Example2.cshtml

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row">
       <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" asp-for="City" class="form-control" maxlength="50" placeholder="Add City Name" required>
       </div>      
       <div class="col-md-4">
              <button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-warning btn-rounded btn-block " data-ftrans="slide" type="submit" style="height:50px; font-size:20px;">Submit</button>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger validation `if(!$("#form_id").valid())` to navigate to the wrongly tab, also to keep current tab status, you can get the `onChange` event to save the information of current in local Storage or query parameter etc and navigate to it on reload.

Comment: Can you elaborate more. ..